# Is this script loading my child theme last?

Tags: php, wordpress

My child-theme stylesheet doesnt seem to be working. I think the script needs to change to load it last but I'm not sure how to change the priority.

[Website url](http://view-source:http://ec2-52-48-176-104.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/)

This the functions.php file:

```html
<?php
function thim_child_enqueue_styles() {
        // Enqueue parent style
        wp_enqueue_style( 'thim-parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'thim_child_enqueue_styles', 100);
```

Comment: I can see the stylesheet is enqueued properly from your Website URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `enqueue` also 'parent-style' and set it as a dependency of 'child-style'. It will ensure that the child theme stylesheet loads after it. So rewrite your `enqueue` function accordingly:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; 

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).